# NHibernate CreateSQLQuery treats entities updated

Tags: nhibernate

i am trying to retrieve data from database via nhibernate's CreateSQLQuery on a stored proceduure. Something like the following code.

then I am basically doing a session transaction commit, however the commit throws an "**cannot update**" exception. It is trying to execute a update statement on CustomEntityDao.

```
        const string selectSQL = "EXEC GetDataSP @Id = :Id";
        var query = Session.CreateSQLQuery(selectSQL);
        query.SetString("Id", "10");
        query.AddEntity(typeof (CustomEntityDao));

        var entityList = query.List<CustomEntityDao>();

        try
        {
            Session.Transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
```

My question is why are the entities been treated as **modified**, as you can see in the code I am only doing a query.

Comment: You should post the mapping and entity in question - often times this is a sign of a mapping mismatch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be there is something else going on your code, what I can suggest is use NHibernate Profiler a trial version of which can be downloaded from www.nhprof.com and monitor the SQL commands that are being fired and notice what objects are being retrieved.

Also I dont understand why are you committing the transaction in the first place.

To solve this particular problem you could always use NHibernates `StatelessSession` which doesnt track entities or you can also use `Session.Evict` and ask Nhibernate to stop tracking particular objects.

Comment: this is just a sample code, where the real code is basically using a UnitOfWork pattern at the http request level. The transaction started in the beginning of the request and commited at the end of the http request. Im putting the code inline because it's easier to understand. Essentially it's doing the same thing.

Comment: I am using Sessino.Evict on the retrieved objects to work around the issue I am having, but i would like to understand what exactly is going on.

Comment: I am guessing somewhere in your unit you are modifying retrieved entities and that is what is trying to be saved.. go through your entire flow and see what is being modified